# Performing sorting query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to make this complex sorting query in MongoDB but I am failing to achieve it.

The model in the collection looks like this:

```
_id: UUID('some-id'),
isDeleted: false,
date: ISODate('some-date'),
responses: [{
    _id: UUID('some-id'),
    userId: UUID('some-id'),
    response: 0
}, {
    _id: UUID('some-id'),
    userId: UUID('some-id'),
    response: 1
}]
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the responses array will always have 2 or 3 objects inside it. Not more, not less. Also, the response will only have three values, either 0, 1, or 2.

And what I want to do is that I want to sort them differently for each user, based on their response.

So let's say that my collection which is called `Events` has a lot of objects in the database. I want that when I filter them, the sorting will be done like this:

```
If my response is 0 and others are either 0 or 1, then sort them always first.

If all responses are 1, sort them after.

Others (if any response is 2, or if my response is 1 but others are 1 or 0), sort them last.
```

We can find if its my response by passing the userId in the query.

On top of that, I will need to have pagination so I will need to implement the $skip and $limit.

Was giving it a try with $unwind then $project trying to do some *scoring* based sorting, but couldn't achieve it.

The scoring sorting would look something like this:

```
if my response is 0 and others are 0 or 1 -> score = 100

if all responses are 1 -> score = 50

all others -> score = 0
```

In this way we could order them by score. But I dont know how I can actually create this property in the fly.

Was thinking that we could create one property like this:

```
$project: {
    myScore: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $in: [
                    UUID('my-user-id'),
                    "$responses.userId"
                ],
                then: "$respones.response", //this is returning array here with all responses
                else: 0
            }
        }
    },
    totalScore: {
        $sum: "$respones.response"
    }
}
```

And then we would be able to do another stage where we sort on these numbers somehow.

Thank you! :)

Comment: I think you'll need 2 examples of input docs and then the desired output docs shown with some comments/description about what is going on, esp. around what "my response" means and exactly how the sort should lay out.   I think you're on the right track with the score field.

Comment: @HenryEcker, true. Sorry for the inconvenience. Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified input set.  We also include a `target` field for help in testing the scoring algo; it is not necessary for the final pipeline, where score is A, B, C for first, middle, and last in sort order.  The score can be "anything" as long as it sorts properly.  I used A, B, and C because it is visually different than the response codes (0,1,2) we are looking at so the pipeline functions are a little more comprehensible but it could be 10, 20, 30 or 5,10,15.

```js
var myUserId = 1;

var r = [
    {
        target: 'C', // last, myUserId response is 1                              
        responses: [
            {userId:0, response:0},
            {userId:1, response:1}
        ]
    }
    ,{
        target: 'C', // last, myUserId response is 1                              
        responses: [
            {userId:1, response:1},
            {userId:0, response:0}
        ]
    }
    ,{
        target: 'A', // first, myUserId response is 0                             
        responses: [
            {userId:1, response:0},
            {userId:0, response:0}
        ]
    }
    ,{
        target: 'B', // mid, all 1s                                               
        responses: [
            {userId:7, response:1},
            {userId:9, response:1}
        ]
    }
    ,{
        target: 'C',  // last, a 2 exists                                         
        responses: [
            {userId:4, response:2},
            {userId:3, response:1},
            {userId:1, response:0}
        ]
    }
];
```

This pipeline will produce the desired output:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {score:
          {$cond: [
              {$in: [2, '$responses.response']}, // any 2s?                       
              'C', // yes, assign last                                            

              {$cond: [ // else                                                   
                  // All responses 1 (i.e. set diff is from 1 is empty set []?    
                  {$eq: [ {$setDifference:['$responses.response',[1]]}, [] ] },
                  'B', // yes, assign mid                                         

                  {$cond: [ // else                                               
                      // Does myUserId have a response of 0?  filter the 
                      // array on these 2 fields and if the size of the 
                      // filtered array != 0, that means you found one!                     
                      {$ne:[0, {$size:{$filter:{input:'$responses',
                                cond:{$and:[
                                    {$eq:['$$this.userId',myUserId]},
                                    {$eq:['$$this.response',0]}
                                ]}
                           }} } ]},
                      'A', // yes, assign first                                   
                      'C',  // else last for rest                                 
                  ]}
          ]}
          ]}
    }}

    ,{$sort: {'score':1}}

    // TEST: Show items where target DOES NOT equal score.  If the pipeline
    // logic is working, this stage will produce zero output; that's
    // how you know it works.                       
    //,{$match: {$expr: {$ne:['$score','$target']}} }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I believe this solution should work. Though, so some changes will be needed here. So i've decided that i want to ignore all items that have response 2 in this filtering, so I would add `$match: { "$responses.response": { $ne: 2 } }` before the `$addFields`. I came up with another solution instead of this. I will add it in the question. I would like to get your feedback on that and let me know what you think.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated the question with my solution :)

Comment: @ErtanHasani  What happened to the all 1s condition?   Well, in any event, the logic is even simpler now so if it works, then great.  Make sure `$responses` array always exists even if empty because `{$size: thingThatIsUnsetAKANull}` will throw an error.  How about marking the response with an accepted answer and upvote since it got you on your way?

Comment: Yes. But now we will first sort by `myScore: 1`, which will show all items that i have scored as 0. Then we will score by `totalScore: -1`, which means that will show those that are all 1s first. Because totalScore will do `sum(arr) / len(array)`, we can get percentage of how many have scored 1. If all have scored 1, that will be shown first as its `totalScore: -1`. Yes, that will always do, as it must be minimum 2 responses in order for an object to be created in collection. Yes, i will do it, since that is technically the answer of the first question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone wondering about this, here's what I came up with. p.s. I also decided that I need to ignore all items if any response contains response 2, so I will focus only on values 0 and 1.

```
db.invites.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "$responses.response": {
                $ne: 2
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "myScore": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {
                       "invite": {
                          // get only object that contains my userId and get firs item from the list (as it will always be one in the list)
                          "$arrayElemAt": [{
                            "$filter": {
                                  "input": "$responses",
                                  "as": "item",
                                  "cond": {"$eq": ["$$item.userId", UUID('some-id')]}
                          }} ,0]
                        }   
                  },
                  // ger response value of that object that contains my userId
                  "in": "$$invite.response"
              }
            },
            // as they are only 0 and 1s in the array items, we can see how many percent have voted with one.
            // totalScore = sum(responses.response) / size(responses)
            "totalScore": {
              $divide: [{$sum: "$responses.response"} , {$size: "$responses"}]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            //sort by my score, so if I have responded with 0, show first
            "myScore": 1,
            //sort by totalScore, so if I have responded 1, show those that have all 1s first.
            "totalScore": -1
        }
    }
])
```